# App Crash - React Redux - not getting params correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-redux, parameters

I'm currently facing an issue with deleting items from a wishlist in my React Redux application. I have implemented a feature where users can add items to their wishlist, but when they try to delete an item, I encounter an issue with passing the correct parameters to my delete function.

Here's a brief overview of my setup:

I'm using React with Redux for state management.
Users can add wishlist items successfully.
The problem arises when I attempt to delete a wishlist item.
Issue:

I'm trying to pass the userId and wishlistItemId as parameters to my handleDeleteWishEl function, which makes an API call to delete the item from the server. However, the wishlistItemId parameter appears to be undefined when it reaches the API call.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
// Inside Wishlist.jsx component
const handleDeleteWish = async (userId, wishlistItemId) => {
  try {
    console.log("userId:", userId);
    console.log("wishlistItemId:", wishlistItemId);

    // API call to delete wishlist item
    await dispatch(handleDeleteWishEl({ userId, wishlistItemId }));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error removing element from wishlist:", error);
  }
};
```

Here's where I get params I'm passing to handleDeleteWish func:

```
 {userWishlist.map((userWishEl) => {
        const itemPercentage = (userWishEl.price / userMoneybox.totalAmount) * 100;
        const itemDiff = userWishEl.price - userMoneybox.totalAmount;

        return (
          <Row key={userWishEl._id} className="mb-4">
            <Button
              onClick={() => handleExpand(userWishEl._id)}
              aria-controls={`collapse-wishEl-${userWishEl._id}`}
              aria-expanded={expandedItems[userWishEl._id]}
              variant="outline-primary"
            >
              <h5>{userWishEl.content}</h5>
              <p>{userWishEl.price} $(US)</p>
            </Button>

            <Collapse in={expandedItems[userWishEl._id]}>
              <div id={`collapse-wishEl-${userWishEl._id}`}>
                <p>{userWishEl.description}</p>

                <p className={`border rounded p-2`}>
                  {userWishEl.price > userMoneybox.totalAmount
                    ? ` You need to save ${itemDiff} $(US) to afford this item`
                    : `You should use the ${itemPercentage.toFixed(
                        2
                      )}% of your total Moneybox to afford
                  this item`}
                </p>
                <div className="d-flex align-items-center gap-3">
                  <Button
                    variant="danger"
                    onClick={() => handleDeleteWish(user._id, userWishEl._id)}
                    disabled={loadingDelete}
                  >
                    {loadingDelete ? "Removing..." : "Delete"}
                  </Button>
                  <Button variant="outline-warning">Edit</Button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Collapse>
          </Row>
        );
      })}
```

I can see that the userId is correctly logged, but wishlistItElId seems to be undefined when it reaches the API call.

Here's a snippet of my Reducer:

```
export const handleDeleteWishEl = createAsyncThunk(
  "user/wishlist/delete",
  async ({ userId, wishlistElId }, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      console.log("userId inside handleDeleteWishEl:", userId);
      console.log("wishlistItemId inside handleDeleteWishEl:", wishlistElId);

      const response = await axios.delete(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVERBASE_URL}/users/${userId}/wishlist/${wishlistElId}/delete`
      );
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.message);
    }
  }
);
```

and how I'm trying to manage the slice:

```
const wishlistSlice = createSlice({
  name: "wishlist",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(handleDeleteWishEl.pending, (state) => {
        state.loading = true;
      })
      .addCase(handleDeleteWishEl.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.wishElDeleted = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(handleDeleteWishEl.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.errorWishEl = action.payload;
      })

      .addCase(getUserWishlist.pending, (state) => {
        state.loading = true;
      })
      .addCase(getUserWishlist.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.wishlist = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(getUserWishlist.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.error = action.payload;
      });
  },
});

export const wishlistState = (state) => state.wishlist.wishlist;
export default wishlistSlice.reducer;
```

What I've Tried:

I've verified that the wishlistItemId is defined when I call the handleDeleteWish function.
I've checked my Redux action and reducer, and they seem to be correctly configured.
I've ensured that the server endpoint for deleting wishlist items is functioning properly.

Request for Help:

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue or how to debug it effectively. If you need more code or information, please let me know, and I'll provide it.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

`wishlistItemId` is passed in the `handleDeleteWishEl` action payload:

```js
await dispatch(handleDeleteWishEl({ userId, wishlistItemId }));
```

But the `handleDeleteWishEl` thunk isn't destructuring it from the payload. It is instead destructuring a `wishlistElId` property, which will *obviously* be undefined since no value was passed for that property.

```js
export const handleDeleteWishEl = createAsyncThunk(
  "user/wishlist/delete",
  async (
    {
      userId,
      wishlistElId // <-- undefined
    },
    thunkAPI
  ) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.delete(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVERBASE_URL}/users/${userId}/wishlist/${wishlistElId}/delete`
      );
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.message);
    }
  }
);
```

## Solution

Either pass `wishlistElId` to `handleDeleteWishEl` or destructure `wishlistItemId` that is passed.

```js
const handleDeleteWish = async (userId, wishlistItemId) => {
  try {
    // API call to delete wishlist item
    await dispatch(handleDeleteWishEl({ userId, wishlistItemId }));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error removing element from wishlist:", error);
  }
};
```

```js
export const handleDeleteWishEl = createAsyncThunk(
  "user/wishlist/delete",
  async ({ userId, wishlistItemId }, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.delete(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVERBASE_URL}/users/${userId}/wishlist/${wishlistItemId}/delete`
      );
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.message);
    }
  }
);
```

or

```js
const handleDeleteWish = async (userId, wishlistElId) => {
  try {
    // API call to delete wishlist item
    await dispatch(handleDeleteWishEl({ userId, wishlistElId }));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error removing element from wishlist:", error);
  }
};
```

```js
export const handleDeleteWishEl = createAsyncThunk(
  "user/wishlist/delete",
  async ({ userId, wishlistElId }, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.delete(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVERBASE_URL}/users/${userId}/wishlist/${wishlistElId}/delete`
      );
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.message);
    }
  }
);
```